# Stack data structure in python

Tags: python

I have 2 issues with the code below:

1. push(o) throws an exception *TypeError: can only assign an iterable*.
2. Should I throw an exception if pop() is invoked on an empty stack ?

   ```
   class Stack(object):

       def __init__(self):
           self.storage = []

       def isEmpty(self):
           return len(self.storage) == 0

       def push(self,p):
           self.storage[:0] = p

       def pop(self):
           """issue: throw exception?"""
           return None
   ```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No need to jump through these loops, See [5.1.1 Using Lists as Stacks](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks)

If you insist on having methods `isEmpty()` and `push()` you can do:

```
class stack(list):
    def push(self, item):
        self.append(item)
    def isEmpty(self):
        return not self
```

Comment: One fundamental issue: all lists operations are now available, so it's more a decorated list that a stack...

Comment: And why exactly is that an issue? If Frankie had an explicit need of preventing people from poking at the internals, he probably would have mentioned it.

Answer (score 25):

You are right to use composition instead of inheritance, because inheritance brings methods in that you don't want to expose.

```
class Stack:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__storage = []

  def isEmpty(self):
    return len(self.__storage) == 0

  def push(self,p):
    self.__storage.append(p)

  def pop(self):
    return self.__storage.pop()
```

This way your interface works pretty much like `list` (same behavior on `pop` for example), except that you've locked it to ensure nobody messes with the internals.

Comment: You can't ensure that nobody messes with the internals. `__storage` can be accessed by `_Stack__storage`

Comment: @Akavall: Sure. And on Linux `/proc/${PID}/mem` [allows you to read/write the process memory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux). As they say: [A lock does not more than keep an honest man, honest](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/3h29vx/a_lock_does_no_more_than_keep_an_honest_man/).

Comment: c'mon this is python not C++, in python every thing is accessible and exposed so why bother with the drama?

Comment: @denizensoft: This is about protecting yourself against Murphy, not Machiavelli. If the user wishes to meddle with the internals and mess things up, they brought it upon themselves; however if they accidentally insert to the front because the API was too permissive, then it's the API designer fault. By restricting the API, errors can be detected sooner (in this case, an exception telling you the method doesn't exist).

Answer (score 11):

I won't talk about the list structure as that's already been covered in this question. Instead I'll mention my preferred method for dealing with stacks:

I always use the `Queue` module. It supports FIFO and LIFO data structures and is thread safe.

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) for more info. It doesn't implement a `isEmpty()` function, it instead raises a `Full` or `Empty` exception if a push or pop can't be done.

Comment: You could also use deques: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects

Answer (score 6):

Stack follows LIFO mechanism.You can create a list and do a normal `append()` to append the element to list and do `pop()` to retrieve the element out of the list which you just inserted.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example for stack class

```
class Stack(object):

   def __init__(self):
      self.items = []

   def push(self, item):
      self.items.append(item)

   def pop(self):
       return self.items.pop()

   def peek(self):
       return self.items[-1]

   def isEmpty(self):
       return len(self.items) == 0
```

Answer (score 5):

```py
    class Stack:
        def __init__(self):
            self.items=[]

        def isEmpty(self):
            return self.items==[]

        def push(self , item):
            self.items.append(item)

        def pop(self):
            return self.items.pop()

        def size(self):
            return len(self.items)

        def peek(self):
            return self.items[-1]
```

**Create a stack**

To create a new stack we can simply use `Stack()`

for example:

```py
     s=Stack()
```

"s" is the name of new stack

**isEmpty**

By using `isEmpty()` we can check our stack is empty or not

for example:

we have two stacks name s1=(0,1,4,5,6) and s2=()

if we use  `print(s1.isEmpty())` it will return `False`

if we use  `print(s2.isEmpty())` it will return `True`

**push**

By using push operation we can add items to top of the stack

we can add "6" to the stack name "s" using

```py
    s.push(6)
```

**pop**

we can use pop operation to remove and return the top item of a stack

if there is a stack name "s" with n amount items (n>0) 
we can remove it's top most item by using

```py
    s.pop()
```

**size**

This operation will return how many items are in the stack

if there is a stack name "s"   s=(1,2,3,4,5,3)

```py
    print(s.size())
```

will return "6"

**peek**
This operation returns the top item without removing it

```py
    print(s.peek())
```

"we can print items of the stack using  `print(s.items)`"

Answer (score 1):

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []
    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            return None
        else:
            return self.stack.pop()
    def push(self, d):
        return self.stack.append(d)
    def peek(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            return None
        else:
            return self.stack[-1]
    def size(self):
        return len(self.stack)
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.size() == 0
```

Comment: @GrantMiller I thought It's self-explanatory. Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score -2):

class stack:

```
def __init__(self,n):##constructor

    self.no = n ##size of stack

    self.Stack = [] ##list for store stack items

    self.top = -1

def push(self):##push method
    if self.top == self.no - 1 :##check full condition
        print("Stack Overflow.....")
    else:
        n = int(input("enter an element :: "))
        self.Stack.append(n) ## in list add stack items use of append method
        self.top += 1##increment top by 1

def pop(self):## pop method

    if self.top == -1: #check empty condition
        print("Stack Underflow....")
    else:
        self.Stack.pop()## delete item from top of stack using pop method
        self.top -= 1 ## decrement top by 1

def peep(self): ##peep method
    print(self.top,"\t",self.Stack[-1]) ##display top item

def disp (self): #display method
    if self.top == -1:# check empty condition
        print("Stack Underflow....")
    else:
        print("TOP \tELEMENT")
        for i in range(self.top,-1,-1): ## print items and top
            print(i," \t",self.Stack[i])
```

n =  int(input("Enter Size :: ")) # size of stack

stk = stack(n) ## object and pass n as size

while(True): ## loop for choice as a switch case

```
print(" 1: PUSH ")
print(" 2: POP ")
print(" 3: PEEP ")
print(" 4: PRINT ")
print(" 5: EXIT ")

option = int(input("enter your choice :: "))

if option == 1:
    stk.push()

elif option == 2:
    stk.pop()

elif option == 3:
    stk.peep()

elif option == 4:
    stk.disp()

elif option == 5:
    print("you are exit!!!!!")
    break
else:
    print("Incorrect option")
```